# Reponsive Text <h1>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Does anybody know how i can make h1 responsive?
It keeps showing large text on mobile browser mode

HTML:
`<div class="index__content"> <h1 style="color:#CC9900">DREAM</h1>`

CSS:

```
index__content{
    position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:100%;
    max-width:655px
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 1):

For the `h1` tag (or anything else) I suggest using `vw` font-size units, or a combination like:

```
font-size:calc(1.1em + .3vw);
```

Comment: Didn't work
Here is the page https://www.coco-mat.com/
The text: "SLEEP ON NATURE
WAKE UP IN A DREAM"

Comment: @P.Tzik - it does work, I just tried. you must play with the values. try `calc(1.2em + .4vw)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use viewport units to scale your text based on width/height of screen.
For your case - applying `xvw` ('x' is desire number) as `font-size`.

**Example -**

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Hello, I'm heading</h1>
```

Here is [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) table from caniuse.com

Comment: Thanks i added your code but when i view it on mobile text ''SLEEP ON NATURE WAKE UP IN A DREAM'' seems a bit small. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use media query so that you can increase `font-size` on mobile. For example - @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    h1 {
     font-size: 8vw;
}
}